# Remove values from a given range and return the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove a range of elements from an array

Let's assume I have an array with given values

```
let arr = [33,44,56,88,332,67,88,33]
```

I gave a range as an input let's say from index 3 to index 6. The output I want: `[33,44,56,33]`

Comment: A simple for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)**

```js
const 
  arr = [33, 44, 56, 88, 332, 67, 88, 33],
  startIndex = 3,
  endIndex = 6,
  newArr = arr.slice(0, startIndex).concat(arr.slice(endIndex + 1));

console.log(newArr);
```

**Using [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [spread (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)**

```js
const 
  arr = [33, 44, 56, 88, 332, 67, 88, 33],
  startIndex = 3,
  endIndex = 6,
  newArr = [...arr.slice(0, startIndex), ...arr.slice(endIndex + 1)];

console.log(newArr);
```

**Using [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**

**Note:** `splice` alters the original array.

```js
const 
  arr = [33, 44, 56, 88, 332, 67, 88, 33],
  startIndex = 3,
  endIndex = 6;
arr.splice(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

For explicitly removing an array element you can do this:

```js
let arr = [ 33, 44, 56, 88, 332, 67, 88, 33 ];
delete arr [ 3 ]; // the array length doesn't change!
console.log( arr );
```

To remove a range in an array, you could try this:

```js
let startIndex = 3;
let stopIndex = 6;
let lengthToRemove = (stopIndex + 1) - startIndex;

let arr = [ 33, 44, 56, 88, 332, 67, 88, 33 ];
arr.splice( startIndex, lengthToRemove );
console.log( arr );
```

Comment: Hey @robni, the only problem with  `arr.splice(startingPoing, length)` i can't give length, as length can be dynamic

Comment: So how do you know the length? Did you want to stop at a specific value? Say your range should be start by value 88 and stop by the  value 33?

Note: the second parameter (lengthToRemove) is the amount of elements to remove from the startingpoint (startingPoint).  If you don't know the amount, you need to know when you want to "stop" the splice.

Comment: I don't know about the length, the only thing I know is a range, from index 3 to index 6 (3,6) or index 1 to index 4 (1,4) @robni

Comment: I edited my answer. The lengthToRemove is now calculated.